# Append a variable to list in tcl

Tags: list, append, tcl

I have a `foreach` loop that does some processing and appends a variable to an existing list as below:

```
set lst_tmp [list];
foreach item $lst_entities {
  set lst_tmp $item;          #1
  set result [::somefunc $item];
  if {$result ne -1} {
    lappend lst_tmp $result;  #2
  }
}

proc ::somefunc {entityType} {
  if {$entityType eq ""} {
    return -1;
  } 
  if {$entityType in {mats props comps}} {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is when my `lst_tmp` gets populated with `$item` at #1, but after #2 the `lst_tmp` value is something like `{item1 result}`. It doesn't evaluate value of `$result` and directly appends the variable name in the list.

I haven't worked on tcl much so I am not sure if I my usage of lappend is wrong or something.

Any comments??

Comment: Could you specify the somefunc procedure here as well to complete your code, it'd be easier to source the issue then ?

Comment: @stark, added the somefunc procedure.

Comment: Let's say if lst_entities contains the elements {1 2 mats props item comps} , what exactly would you want lst_tmp to look like using your bit of code ?

Comment: `somefunc` looks reasonable, except for being put below the code that calls it. The main loop has one major issue: you're setting `lst_tmp` before the loop and inside it as well. What are you trying to actually achieve? Give what you want to get out at the end when you have a defined input…

Comment: Works fine for me: set lst_tmp [list];


set lst_entities  "mats props comps"

proc ::somefunc {entityType} {
  if {$entityType eq ""} {
    return -1;
  } 
  if {$entityType in {mats props comps}} {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

foreach item $lst_entities {
  set lst_tmp $item;          #1
  set result [::somefunc $item]

  if {$result ne -1} {
    lappend lst_tmp $result;  #2
  }
}
puts $lst_tmp

This outputs 

comps 1

Are you evaluating this in {} block somewhere or otherwise.